# Verification $\epsilon-\delta$ of this (false) limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

As always, I demand some clarification and / or to right my wrongs...

> $$\lim_{x\to 8} x^2 - 2x + 1 = 49$$

The limit is obviously false, but let's verify it. This is where I faced some troubles. For example:

$$|x^2 - 2x - 48 | < \epsilon$$

$$48 - \epsilon < x^2 - 2x < 48 + \epsilon$$

How could I manage this expression? I have several questions about this. I know I should split them but I think it's not the case so:

**Question 1.**

Could I write something like

$$x^2 - 2x \leq x^2$$ and then proceed in this sense? If I can: why can I? And If I cannot, why?

Also, it would be possible instead to use?
$$x^2 - 2x \geq 2x$$

This makes me confused about this: when should I use a majorisation $\leq$ and when $\geq$?

For example, following the first case (if possible) I would obtain

$$\sqrt{48 - \epsilon} < x < \sqrt{48 + \epsilon}$$

Which for sure guarantees the neighbourhood of $x$ is not $8$, as wanted. Is this acceptable?

**Question 2.**

Suppose instead I proceed this way:

$$|(x-8)(x+6)| < \epsilon$$

$$|x-8| < \frac{\epsilon}{|x+6|}$$

Now since I know $x\to 8$, I can for sure tell $7 < x < 9$, that is adding $6$

$$13 < x+6 < 15$$
So
$$\frac{1}{x+6} > \frac{1}{15}$$

And then I could write

$$|x-8| < \frac{\epsilon}{15}$$

So apparently I have managed to find a control $\delta_{epsilon}$. The question is: how this would make me understand the limits is wrong?

Note the two approaches are different and rise different questions, and I needed to write down them all here because once someone clarified these to me, I guess I would be able to reason by myself having understood some finicky rules which now put me on hold.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What makes you think the limit is wrong?

Comment: @Robbie Pardon! I miswrote the whole limit... Yikes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we *do* have$$\lim_{x\to8}x^2-2x+1=49,$$because, given $\varepsilon>0$, we have\begin{align}x^2-2x+1-49&=x^2-64-2(x-8)\\&=(x-8)(x+8)-2(x-8)\\&=(x-8)(x+6).\end{align}So, if $|x-8|<1$, $|x+6|>13$ , and therefore, if $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\delta{13}\right\}$, then$$|x-8|<\delta\implies|x^2-2x+1-49|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: How would I have reasoned if, say, the limit were $59$? Could you pleas provide me some answer about my questions in that case?

Comment: Then you could prove that, for each $\delta>0$, there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x-8|<\delta$ and that $|x^2-2x+1-59|\geqslant1$.

Comment: I got lost: how we can say |x-1| < 1, considering $x\to 8$?

Comment: I've edited my answer.